# Cloud Build could not create an image and publish it to Container Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

My objective is to create a CI/CD for a Django Rest Framework project. I am using `Google Source Repository` for version control and `Google Compute Engine VM` instance for deployment. `Dockerfile` of this project is able to create image and I am also able to run that image.

Now, on `Source Repository` when I merge other branches with master branch the cloud trigger should be able to create a new image, push it to the `Container Repository` and update an existing instance of `Google Compute Engine VM` with the new container.

So far on every push to master branch `Cloud Build - Trigger` are able create an image and push it over `Container Registry`. But `Cloud Build - Trigger` uses `Dockerfile` not `cloudbuild.yaml`.

This is `cloudbuild.ymal` which I crated.

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/myproject-100/docker'
      args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/myproject-100/dropoff:', '.' ]

    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      args: [ 'compute', 'instance', 'update-container', 'dropoff-staging-v3', --zone='northeast1-a' ]
    
    images:
    - 'gcr.io/myproject-100/dropoff'
```

The `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` are in the root directory of project folder. When I run command `gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml` I get this error -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) parsing cloudbuild.yaml: while parsing a block collection
  in "cloudbuild.yaml", line 2, column 5
expected <block end>, but found u'?'
  in "cloudbuild.yaml", line 4, column 5
```

1. What has caused this error and how can I fix this.
2. Do you think the way I wrote `cloudbuild.yaml` will help me achieve my objective.

Comment: yaml files are very tricky to create. You must use space and not tab. Did you check if there are no tabs?

Comment: Please refrain from posting your project id on public resources in the future, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `cloudbuild.yaml` seems completely unrelated,

because line 2 and 4, column 5 has no "u"; the whole line doesn't have one.

See [YAML in a Nutshell](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_kubernetes/yaml_in_a_nutshell) for how to get your indentation right; it should look more alike this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/dropoff-280002/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/dropoff-280002/dropoff:', '.' ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: [ 'compute', 'instance', 'update-container', 'dropoff-staging-v3', --zone='northeast1-a' ]    
images:
  - 'gcr.io/dropoff-280002/dropoff'
```

Or see this one [`cloudbuild.yaml`](https://github.com/syslogic/cloudbuild-android/blob/master/cloudbuild.yaml) ...which is known to be working.